# Trying to join two tables, one ordered to get flagged row first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

**prt_gebouw**

```
id  | name
----+------------
1   | Building A
2   | Building B
3   | Building C
```

**prt_image**

```
id  | building_id   | name      | is_primary
----+---------------+-----------+------------
1   | 1             | img1.jpg  | 0
2   | 1             | img2.jpg  | 0
3   | 2             | img3.jpg  | 0
4   | 1             | img4.jpg  | 1
5   | 2             | img5.jpg  | 1
```

As you can see here, some buildings have more than one image and some have none. When a building has one image or more, only one image can be marked as primary; can, for this is not mandatory.

Now, what I am trying to do is list all buildings (each building once) and join this with the images table, preferrably the primary image, empty cells if no image can be found.

So first I tried this:

```
SELECT
    pgb.id,
    pgb.name,
    img.id AS image_id,
    img.name AS image_name,
    img.is_primary AS is_primary
FROM
    prt_gebouw pgb
    LEFT JOIN prt_image img ON pgb.id = img.object_id AND img.kind = 'object'
GROUP BY pgb.id
ORDER BY img.is_primary DESC, pgb.id ASC;
```

I suspect that the grouping is done before the ordering, because the wrong image is joined with each building that has more than one image ("wrong" being here: not the primary one).

Then I tried:

```
SELECT
    pgb.id,
    pgb.name,
    img.id AS image_id,
    img.name AS image_name,
    img.is_primary
FROM
    prt_gebouw pgb
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM prt_image ORDER BY is_primary DESC) AS img ON img.object_id = pgb.id
ORDER BY pgb.id ASC;
```

I was hoping that for each building the primary image would be listed first, but not so. I suspect this is also the problem in the previous query, but is it?
And, more importantly, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a correlated subquery might be easier for what you want:

```
select pgb.*,
       (select i.id
        from prt_image i
        where i.object_id = pgb.id and i.kind = 'object'
        order by is_primary desc
        limit 1
       ) as img_id
from prt_gebouw pgb;
```

If you want the other fields from the image, join them in afterwards:

```
select pgb.*, i.*  -- I'm using `*` for inconvenience; list the columns here
from (select pgb.*,
             (select i.id
              from prt_image i
              where i.object_id = pgb.id and i.kind = 'object'
              order by is_primary desc
              limit 1
             ) as img_id
      from prt_gebouw pgb
     ) pgb left join
     prt_image i
     on pgb.img_id = i.id;
```

Comment: I didn't think putting a select in a select was even possible. Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Such correlated subqueries are very powerful under some circumstances.  The "correlation clause" is the `WHERE` condition(s) that match the inner table with the outer table.  In general, you want indexes on the columns used for the match.